# Keeping a table column empty when it is indexed as unique

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to keep a table column empty if it's defined as unique?

Table schema

```
      Column       |          Type          |   Modifiers   | Description 
-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-------------
 id                | integer                | not null      | 
 name              | character varying(64)  |               |
```

Indexes

```
Indexes:
    "clients_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "clients_name_idx" UNIQUE, btree (name)
Has OIDs: yes
```

Due to modifications to the application sometimes the name column needs to be empty, is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column can contain `NULL` values, then that is OK, as `NULL` is not included in the index.

Note that some databases don't implement the standard properly (some versions of SQL Server only allowed one `NULL` value per unique constraint, but I'm sure if that is still the case).

Answer (score 0):

Using NULL is the better option, but you could also use a conditional unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_clients_name ON clients (name) WHERE name <> '';
```

And avoid oid's, these are useless and obsolete.